# MySQL - extract number from data field using SUBSTRING

Tags: mysql, substring

I'd like to extract the number between `NUMBER` and `;`. So far I can extract the data up to the number, but I don't want anything after the number. e.g.,

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(field, LOCATE('NUMBER=', rrule) + 7)
FROM table
```

Data field:

```
DATA:PASS=X12;NUMBER=331;FIELD=1
DATA:PASS=X12;NUMBER=2;FOO=BAR;FIELD=1
```

Desired Output:

```
331
2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) functions:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(field, 'NUMBER=', -1),
    ';',
  1)
FROM
  tablename
```

Please see an [example fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0083b/1).

The inner SUBSTRING_INDEX will return everything after the NUMBER= string, while the second will return everything before the ; returned by the inner function.